# socat ignoring -v -x

Tags: bash, socat

I am trying to use socat to capture serial traffic on a USB-to-serial adapter using this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ 0 != ${EUID} ]] ; then
    sudo "$0" "$@"
    exit $?
fi

SOCAT_OPTIONS="-d -d -v -x PTY,raw,link=/dev/socat,wait-slave,mode=0660,group=dialout /dev/ttyUSB0,raw"
socat $SOCAT_OPTIONS
```

However, socat appears to be ignoring the "-v -x".

My socat options are based on the example at this site:

http://mmdolze.users.sourceforge.net/serial-port-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

When I remove "wait-slave" option, I see the output from "-v -x".

I wish I knew why that makes a difference. The man page does not give any clues.